# WiFi sees some 5GHz AP's but not mine

Tags: networking, wireless, hardware

I've got my router broadcasting two wifi networks - one on 2.4GHz and one on 5GHz. Using a wifi scanner on my phone, I can see that both networks are available:

[image: two wifi endpoints]

However when I scan for these endpoints on my desktop using a AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter from Qualcomm, while it is able to see the 2.4GHz network fine it cannot see the 5GHz one at all.

Why would this be so? It does see other 5Ghz networks in the area:

```
sudo iwlist wlo1 scan
wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: AE:F8:CC:06:1F:18
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ziggo"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000009cb5a032
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00055A6967676F
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 0706455520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                    IE: Unknown: 3B025100
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2D0017FFFFFF00000000000000C2010100000000001004870100
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080500000200000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: <>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"<my network>8-2.4GHz"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000009cb59dd8
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00135A6967676F383730383433382D322E3447487A
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 0706455520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 46050200000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3B025100
                    IE: Unknown: 46050200000000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2D0017FFFFFF00000000000000C2010100000000001004870100
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080500080200000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD860050F204104A00011010440001021057000101103B000103104700105B8D809E1B7D5AF2B391833B950A7DD41021000643656C656E6F10230006434C323430301024000232301042000531323334351054000800060050F204000110110012576972656C65737320415020434C32343030100800020000103C0001031049000600372A000120
          Cell 03 - Address: 18:35:D1:27:CE:FF
                    Channel:44
                    Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)
                    Quality=44/70  Signal level=-66 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ziggo5072369"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000005e12f11f09
                    Extra: Last beacon: 3368ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C5A6967676F35303732333639
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 03012C
                    IE: Unknown: 073C4555202401172801172C01173001173401173801173C011740011764011E68011E6C011E70011E74011E78011E7C011E80011E84011E88011E8C011E
                    IE: Unknown: 460573D000000C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEF091BFFFFFF0000000000000000000100000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D162C050500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0805000F0200000040
                    IE: Unknown: BF0CB2018033EAFF0000EAFF0000
                    IE: Unknown: C005012A00FCFF
                    IE: Unknown: C30402D2D2D2
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD9F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700105A1A5253659656489329A74B8B4A69671021001C41746865726F7320436F6D6D756E69636174696F6E732C20496E632E102300044150787810240008415078782D7878781042001253657269616C204E756D62657220486572651054000800060050F20400011011000941746865726F734150100800020104103C0001021049000600372A000120
          Cell 04 - Address: E8:48:B8:76:E7:90
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=45/70  Signal level=-65 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Donotpeek"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000350360840e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0009446F6E6F747065656B
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD0117FFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000001804871100
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080000080000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0B05020000127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 46050200000000
                    IE: Unknown: 330E040102030405060708090A0B0C0D
                    IE: Unknown: 200103
                    IE: Unknown: 23023F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0706444520010D23
                    IE: Unknown: BF0CB179C233EAFF9204EAFF9204
                    IE: Unknown: C005000000EAFF
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C430B000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD21000CE708000000BF0CB101C0332AFF92042AFF9204C0050000002AFFC303010202
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E001D0F100204000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD1E003192100204000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
          Cell 05 - Address: 18:35:D1:27:CE:F9
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ziggo5072369"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000005e27af80fe
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C5A6967676F35303732333639
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706455520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 460573D000000C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFF0000000000000000000001000000000406E6A70C00
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0805000F0200000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD9F0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700105A1A5253659656489329A74B8B4A69671021001C41746865726F7320436F6D6D756E69636174696F6E732C20496E632E102300044150787810240008415078782D7878781042001253657269616C204E756D62657220486572651054000800060050F20400011011000941746865726F734150100800020104103C0001021049000600372A000120
          Cell 06 - Address: F6:57:40:9A:1A:48
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ziggo"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000e842d48e13
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00055A6967676F
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706455520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFF0000000000000000000001000000000406E6A70C00
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080500000200000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          Cell 07 - Address: 2A:35:D1:27:CE:F9
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Ziggo"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000005e27aec774
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00055A6967676F
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B968C129824
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 0706455520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 3204B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAD011BFFFF0000000000000000000001000000000406E6A70C00
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601080400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080500000200000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101840003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: DD0900037F01010000FF7F
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
          Cell 08 - Address: F4:E3:FB:0B:1E:28
                    Channel:8
                    Frequency:2.447 GHz (Channel 8)
                    Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"VFNL-0B1E21"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000004cc9579718d
                    Extra: Last beacon: 5340ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000B56464E4C2D304231453231
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030108
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0104
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1608000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080100000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD1000E0FC80000000230000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A000110104400010210470010FEE92F84D03DC72AD390C7806836E245103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180203000C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 09 - Address: 90:5C:44:DA:33:57
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ZiggoDF4EEFE"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000004011961d97
                    Extra: Last beacon: 68ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000C5A6967676F44463445454645
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 03010B
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 0706455520010D14
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC0117FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D160B000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080100080000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 0B0501005B127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 46052200000000
                    IE: Unknown: DDA70050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001088547A001DD211B286015543A04A64431021001852616C696E6B20546563686E6F6C6F67792C20436F72702E1023001C52616C696E6B20576972656C6573732041636365737320506F696E74102400065254323836301042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000952616C696E6B415053100800020000103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Bands 2,4GHz and 5GHz use a set of "[channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels)" to communicate with devices.

Your router is using channel 108 for 5GHz.

1. Try to find out which channels your wireless card supports:

[How to find supported wireless channels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137894/how-do-i-find-out-if-my-wireless-card-supports-5-ghz)

```
iwlist wlo1 freq
```

2. Try to change the router`s channel for 5GHz(from the router admin interface) from 108 to a supported channel (eg 44 as the displayed network)

As a reference, [what are Wifi channels](https://www.minim.com/blog/wifi-channels-explained-what-is-wifi-channel-width)

> WiFi channels are smaller bands within WiFi frequency bands that are used by your wireless network to send and receive data. Depending on which frequency band your router is using, you have a certain number of WiFi channels to choose from:

- 11 WiFi channels are in the 2.4 GHz frequency band
- 45 WiFi channels are in the 5 GHz frequency band

Comment: Thanks - my card only supports channels in the 20MHz range it would seem:

```
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
```